# OleDb SQL Insert Statement

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

My bill table has the columns Item, Price and Quantity and my following codes are fetching the item and price from another table (Products), however I would also like to insert another item for Quantity. How can i combine that in this statement? Quantity = 1

`INSERT INTO Bill (Item, Price) SELECT Product, Price FROM Products WHERE Product = 'Soft Drink'";`

Comment: You are creating confusion, I think you have to post your table schema and your query with example to help you in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a sub-query into your main select statement:

```
INSERT INTO Bill (Item, Price)
SELECT Produce, Price, (Select Quantity FROM SomewhereElse) 
WHERE Products = 'Soft Drink'
```

Or you could use a variable:

```
declare @Quantity decimal(18,2)
select @Quantity = Quantity from SomewhereElse

INSERT INTO Bill (Item, Price)
SELECT Produce, Price, @Quantity WHERE Products = 'Soft Drink'
```

Comment: The tag `sql` is generic. The particular flavour is `ms-access` so part two of your answer will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following statement:

`"INSERT INTO Bill (Item, Price, Quantity) SELECT Product, Price, '1' as Quantity FROM Products WHERE Product = 'Soft Drink'";`

Comment: You are inserting quantity as text (string) it should be numeric, at least I hope the field (column) quantity is numeric in your table so: `1 as Quantity`, that is, no quotes.